# clone and append in jquery mobile- doubling up?

Tags: jquery-mobile, append, clone

When I clone and append/prepend html fragments in jquery mobile, fragment is doubling up.  You can plug this code and test.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

    <!-- standard Jquery/jQuery Mobile Libraries -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b2/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b2/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.js"></script>   
    </head> 

    <body>  
    <div data-role="page" id="mainmenu">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="inline"></div>

    <div class="ui-body ui-body-c">
        <div data-role="content">   

        <a href="#" class="preShowHTML">click to view HTML</a>      
        <pre>
        <span id="HTMLOut">
        my HTML output goes here...
        </span>
        </pre>
    </div>
    </div>  


    <div id='groupA' class='preGroups'>         
        <div id='placeholder' ></div>   
    </div>

    <fieldset class="ui-grid-a" data-inline="true">     
        <div class="ui-block-b"><button type="submit"  class="addPart" data-theme="a" data-icon="plus">Add Serial/Part</button></div>
    </fieldset>

    <div id='template'>                 
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <input type="range" name="QTY" id="preQuant01" value="1" min="1" max="10"/>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<style>
#template,  #HTMLOut, #XMLOut{
    display:none;
}
</style>


<script>
counter = 1;

$(document).ready(function() {

/* Add a listeners to Add Part */   
    $('.addPart').click(function() {    
            myClone = $('#template').clone();           
            myClone.attr("id", "template-" + counter);  
            counter++;
            myClone.appendTo("#placeholder").trigger( "create" );
            // myClone.appendTo("#placeholder").page(); does not work in this version?

        return false;
    });   

    // Toggle Show/Hide HTML
    $('.preShowHTML').click(function() {    
         $("#HTMLOut").text($("body").html());
         $("#HTMLOut").toggle();
        return false;
    });             
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

AJAX might make it slightly cleaner but here is a start:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").live("pageshow", function () { 
        counter = 0;
        $(".addPart").click(function() {    
                counter++;
                $("#placeholder").append('<div  id="template-'+counter+'"><div data-role="fieldcontain"><input type="range" name="slider" class="ui-slider-input ui-input-text ui-body-null ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset ui-body-c" id="slider'+counter+'" value="0" min="0" max="100" /></div></div>');
                $("#template-"+counter).trigger("create");

            return false;
        });   

    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Not quite... I can't find anything on page() function. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: JQM marks up all the elements of the page.  After the DOM has loaded, it is much easier to have JQM handle the markup, let it do the hard part.  The "page()" function makes that easy...

Comment: I hadn't really tested that code... after looking back at it I will make some revisions... the jquery clone after the page has already loaded is creating the slider with the correct markup and the page function is actually marking it up again.  one contains the sliding jquery mobile functionality while the other is simply styled to look like one but doesn't actually do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think the counter is in the wrong place.  However this does not make the example any more functional.

```
myClone = $('#template').clone();           
myClone.attr("id", "template-" + counter);  
//counter++;
myClone.appendTo("#placeholder");
$('#template-'+counter).page();                
counter++;
```

I am not sure that this is correct approach - cloning html after jquery mobile has applied it's listeners and formatting.